Nested navigation items that need to be displayed on desktop next to each other equally sized
I have a weird case of a deeply nested navigation items, that each level(goes up to 3) need to be displayed into equal boxes next to each other, as if they were not nested visually.
The structure cannot be changed.
Can there be a grid or any other css solution for this?


<ul class="subcategory level-1">
  <li>
    Some link
    <ul class="subcategory level-2">
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>
        Some link
        <ul class="subcategory level-3">
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Some link
    <ul class="subcategory level-2">
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>
        Some link
        <ul class="subcategory level-3">
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Some link
    <ul class="subcategory level-2">
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>
        Some link
        <ul class="subcategory level-3">
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>




    Some link
    
      Some link
Some link

        Some link
        
          Some link
Some link
Some link



    Some link
    
      Some link
Some link

        Some link
        
          Some link
Some link
Some link



    Some link
    
      Some link
Some link

        Some link
        
          Some link
Some link
Some link



Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"equally sized" - are you okay with specifying a width, or do you want this to be automatically determined based on the width of the "widest" item?

Try this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/3qyfm0wt/1/
It doesn't display in a single line but in a even grid instead.
#main-list{
    list-style: none;
    width: 780px;

}

#main-list li{
    width: 193px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px white solid;
}

#main-list ul{
    list-style: none;
}

#main-list ul li{
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main-list ul { padding: 0px;}


Thank you, I will try to work my way around with this one
